# How can you disable the ChangePasswordAtLogon flag on a newly created AD user through C# DirectoryServices API?

Tags: active-directory, ldap, directoryservices

Whenever I create a new user through the System.DirectoryServices API I end up with a user account that has its ChangePasswordAtLogon set to on (checked in the properties dialog). I've tried a number of searches and attributes and can't seem to find a way to turn this off.

Answer (score 4):

It is stored under the attribute [ms-DS-User-Account-Control-Computed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms677840.aspx) as a bitfield flag `UF_PASSWORD_EXPIRED`, however attribute is read only and you can not set or unset that flag directly.

What you need to do is set the value of [pwdLastSet to 0 or -1](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa746510.aspx) to set or clear the flag.

The following example and more information can be found on [this MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/ms180915.aspx) page on "Managing User Passwords" with `System.DirectoryServices`

```cs
usr.Properties["pwdLastSet"].Value = -1; // To turn on, set this value to 0.
usr.CommitChanges();
```

Comment: Have you tried committing the changes to create the user then after that do the above two lines? I have had similar issues where password related things did not work until after the user was committed to the directory.

Comment: @brushleaf From what I remember, you have to create the user and commit, then set the property and commit again.